# Curly braces with exclamation and dollar sign in single qoutes

Tags: apex

How can we consider this expression:

```
System.debug('{!$Credential.MyPleasure.accountId}');
```

I believe that `$Credential.MyPleasure` is supposed to return back the set of NamedCredential fields  (like accountId) but `System.debug` just shows me only the `{!$Credential.MyPleasure.accountId}` string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These merge fields in the request are only populated during the callout. You can't use `System.debug` to see their values.

Your Apex code doesn't know which Named Credential you are going to use until you actually do the callout itself.

The Salesforce documentation for this is here: [Merge Fields for Apex Callouts That Use Named Credentials](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm)

Comment: fred, may i ask you to share salesforce docs tied to this topic?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials_merge_fields.htm